# show validation error when duplicate values are inserted MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

working in MVC project 
want to generate an error meassage when duplicate records are going to insert

how do i check duplicate records in create method?

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Employee _Checkin)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                Utilities.SaveEntityInstance(_Checkin);
                return new AjaxAwareRedirectResult("/Checkin/Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("Create", _Checkin);
            }
        }
```

when i insert new employee form fields are 
empname empjoindate empid

if I tried to insert same employee info again which is present into table
I should have to show message.

how can i do this?

Comment: Before Utilities.SaveEntityInstance(_Checkin);, just check if user exists. Or Modify the Utilities.SaveEntityInstance(_Checkin)code to throw exception if user exists (ideally check against empid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a check if Username already exists (ideally checking in your DB code which does the save whether the Emp ID already exists.  Then use something like the below:

Edit - the first parameter here should match the field in your model which you want to add the error too.

```
 ModelState.AddModelError("EmpName", "Employee Name already exists. Please enter a different Employee Name.");
```